# Installing Jenkins on RHEL 6 getting error "No valid crumb was included in the request"

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, rhel

I've just installed Jenkins on an AWS EC2. However when I go to configure Jenkins from the browser I get the following error immediately after I select install recommended plugins:

```
An error occurred during installation: No valid crumb was included in the request
```

When I looked up this error, it seems it was a known issue but was resolved last year.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12875

However I am still encountering it on a stable build version.

**Installation on RHEL 6:**

- sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
- sudo rpm --import https://jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key
- sudo yum install jenkins

**Running Jenkins**

- sudo service jenkins start

Does anybody know a workaround or how to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: I tried editing my `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` and added `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhudson.security.csrf.requestfield=crumb"` but to no avail